# Search Data in an ArrayList that saved in a file and print it out in a texfield

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, textfield

i have this button that save input data via textfield in an ArrayLists and save it to a file.

```
private void btnSaveAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(rad_savings);
    bg.add(rad_checking);

    account.setAccountName(txt_accountname.getText());
    account.setAccountNo(txt_accountnumber.getText());
    list.add(account);

    String fileName = "bank.txt";
    FileWriter file = null;

    try {
        file = new FileWriter(fileName,true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        for(BankAccount str: list) {
            pw.println(str);
        }

        pw.flush();
        pw.println("\n");


    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Can't create your account!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JFrameNewAccount.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JFrameNewAccount.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I also have a textfield for Withdraw_AccountName and Withdraw_AccountNumber, how can i search the account number inside the arraylists? When Withdraw_AccountNumber match with the account number in the arraylists, it will also display the account name in the Withdraw_AccountName. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to iterate over the BankAccounts to find the one that has the account number you need.

```
for(BankAccount account: list) {
    if (account.getAccountNo().equals(accountNumberToSearchFor)){
        // found ya! set the correct text field
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could store the BankAccounts in a Map, where you make a map of account numbers to bank accounts; or, you could also make a custom comparator and use a Java Collection that is now sorted by the account number.

Comment: I hope they are stored as `int`s ;)

Comment: Hello, could you please help me what is missing? I just want also to display the accountname

`private void txt_wdaccountnumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        for(BankAccount account: list){
            if(account.getAccountNo() == txt_wdaccountnumber.getText()){
                //get the accontname and display it in txt_wdaccountname
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No records found!");
            }
        }
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }    `

Comment: I've tried the below but nothing happens.

`private void txt_wdaccountnumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
            
        for(BankAccount account: list){
            if(account.getAccountNo().equals(txt_wdaccountnumber.getText())){
                txt_wdaccountname.setText(account.getAccountName());
                txt_wdaccountname
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No records found!");`

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens?  Also is the account number a text field or a primitive?

Comment: Account number is a textfield. i try to place the code in actionevent of txt_wdaccountnumber, when user input a number in txt_wdaccountnumber, it will search the account number in arraylist, when it found, the account name associated with that account number will also display in txt_wdaccountname, but it seems i've missed something or not working?

Comment: Yes. Here's what in the actionevent of txt_wdaccountnumber

`private void txt_wdaccountnumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
            
        for(BankAccount account: list){
            if(account.getAccountNo().equals(txt_wdaccountnumber.getText())){
                txt_wdaccountname.setText(account.getAccountName());
                //get the accontname and display it in txt_wdaccountname
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No records found!");`

Comment: Print out the what you are getting from txt_wdaccountnumber.getText(), make sure it doesn't have any spaces or newline characters

Comment: could you please provide me an example?

Comment: System.out.println("search no='"+txt_wdaccountnumber.getText()+"'");

Comment: I've tried but still it didn't display any output. Data was also saved in a file "bank.txt.

Comment: It's got to be a problem with either calling the method, or with not getting the right data from the GUI. What I gave you will search the list for the values, but these are other problems that really are dependent on your program

Comment: could you please provide me a code solution for that? I've already stuck here for almost a week :(

Comment: That's outside the scope of this question.  Narrow down your problem and ask that question :)

Comment: I see. by the way, thanks mate for tips. How can i accept this and vote it?

Comment: You can just click the `checkmark` which is by the up/down vote.  You can't upvote until you get 15 reputation, so you won't be able to do that now